# Почему запрос выполнятся под Windows, а под Linux ошибка: "ORA-01722: invalid number"?

Tags: python, sql, oracle, cx-oracle

Есть Python/SQL скрипт, который написан под Windows.

Все элементарно просто, выполняю запрос и делаю `fetchall()`.

Проблема начинается, когда я пытаюсь запустить этот же скрипт на сервере Linux.  Запрос выполняется точно такое же время как и под Windows, но при выполнении `fetchall()` даёт ошибку:

> cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01722: invalid number

Запрос просто `select`, и итоговая выборка примерно 3000 строк.

Устанвливаю соединение:

```
connection = cx_Oracle.connect(user_name, password, dsn_tns,encoding='UTF-8',nencoding='UTF-8')

cursor = connection.cursor() 

cursor.execute(_SQL)
```

Под Windows - всё нормально, а под Linux - ошибка

В какую сторону смотреть? В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Можете, пожалуйста, показать запрос? Пока только подозрения, что драйвер для взаимодействия с Oracle под Windows и Linux по-разному интерпретирует запросы.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Всё очень просто. Запрос содержит неявное преобразование типов данных.

Например, даты или числа в строчное значение (или наоборот). Так как национальные настройки на Windows и Linux могут отличаться, то выполненение одного и того же запроса под разными ОС может привести, как в вопросе, к ошибкам, или, что гораздо хуже, к различным результатам запроса.

Решение (*первое предпочтительней*):

1. Изменить запрос так, чтобы он содержал только явные преобразования типов данных.
2. Переменной окружения `NLS_LANG` установить одинаковые  национальные настройки сессий на обоих системах.

---

Простейший пример того, что может привести к ошибке:

```
select 0 + '1,23' res from dual;

       RES
----------
      1,23
```

А теперь:

```
alter session set nls_territory='America'
/
select 0 + '1,23' res from dual;
```

> ORA-01722: invalid number